# Independent Overflow-y Scrolling on Sidebar and Content

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to add independent `overflow-y` scrolling on 2 elements on my page: the `#sidebar` and the main content in `#my-modules`.

As you can see in this **[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pjou7trg/)**, it doesn't seem to be working. The scrollbar appears on the whole document, which is not what I would like. I want the design to take full height of the browser without any scrollbars. Any overflow content in `#sidebar` and `#my-modules` should get the scrollbar. I also can't figure out how to add even margins between the modules.

HTML:

```
<div id="top-bar" class="grid wrap">
  <div class="unit whole">
    <p>Top Bar</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="content" class="grid wrap">

  <div id="sidebar" class="unit one-fifth">
    <p>Sidebar</p>
  </div>

  <div id="my-modules">
    <div class="unit one-third module">
      <p>Module 1</p>
    </div>
    <div class="unit one-third module">
      <p>Module 2</p>
    </div>
    <div class="unit one-third module">
      <p>Module 3</p>
    </div>
    <div class="unit half module">
      <p>Module 4</p>
    </div>
    <div class="unit half module">
      <p>Module 5</p>
    </div>
    <div class="unit whole module">
      <p>Module 6</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 0.875em;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

#top-bar,
#sidebar,
.module {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

#content {
  height: 100%;
}

#sidebar {
  height: 100%;
}

#my-modules {
  float: left;
  width: 80%;
  padding: 0;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.module {
  height: 220px;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you set a height on #my-modules. You'll get a scroll bar. Because you're not setting a height, the div will just expand to fit the content.

Comment: You're right - that works! Any idea how I can get even margins between the modules in `#my-modules`?

Comment: Depends what you mean by even margins. If you're setting your widths in percentages, then I'd do the same for margins. You'll just need to account for module width, based on your margins. If you want fixed sized gaps between, then I'd maybe do something like `width:calc(30% - 40px); margin:0 20px;` for example

Comment: Ok, let me try this. By margins I meant, I would just like to add some spacing between the modules. If I used `margin: 10px;` then some of the modules will end up 20px if they are on top or bottom of each other.

Comment: Depends on your design. You can do something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/pjou7trg/1/ But it might not work perfectly for you. Flexbox would solve this nicely, if you haven't had a look at [Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) before, definitely a good time to now.

Comment: @mapr How'd you get on?

Comment: I ended up using a combination of `width: calc()` and `margin` as you suggested to have even spacing between my modules.